# Magento 2 :My account link not working

Tags: magento2

After sign in to account, page redirect to my account page and click on some other page and again click on my account link not working.
 My code:

```
<li class="authorization-link">
    <?php if ($block->isLoggedIn()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $block->getAccountUrl() ?>">
            <?php echo __('My Account') ?>
        </a>
   <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

Comment: You can replace $block->getAccountUrl() with $this->getUrl('customer/account/create');

Comment: Thanks Rakesh its working, but i want  $this->getUrl('customer/account');

Comment: I have just updated answer please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like below code,

```
  <li class="authorization-link">
        <?php if ($block->isLoggedIn()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account') ?>">
                <?php echo __('My Account') ?>
            </a>
       <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
```